# after installing jdk1.8.0_25 I do not have a 'Java Runtime Envrionment' entry in Registry

Tags: java, windows, registry, runtime

I installed jdk1.8.0_25 putting the install files in the D: (the C: is nearly full) on Windows 7. I then set my JAVA_HOME environment variable.

On the C: and D: the javac command is found and appears to run correctly.
On the D: the java command is found and appears to run correctly.

On the C: java is not found and I get the following error:
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment

I looked in the Registry and found the 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment' is missing. I worked around this by removing java.exe and javaw.exe from the C:\windows\System32 directory.

Now the java command appears to run correctly on both the C: and D: however I am concerned that the registry entry 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment' is still missing.

Can I manually add this to the registry? Do I need to add this to the registry? Will not having this registry entry cause problems?

Comment: You don't need such registry. Just make sure that `javac`, `java` and related programs can be reached by any point in the console by making them available in `PATH` system environment variable.

Comment: Thank You.  I am new to working with these tools (maven, java, intelliJ) and wanted to be sure I wasn't going to run into hard to trace "weirdness" when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem on my pc.

Save this to "java-env.reg":

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit]
"CurrentVersion"="1.8"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.8]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk8"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment]
"CurrentVersion"="1.8"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk8\\jre"
"RuntimeLib"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk8\\jre\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll"
```

Change version info to your version, and change pathes to your own path.

Execute the regfile.

Hopes this help you.

PS: Someone says just reinstall your jdk&jre will fix it, but I didn't have a try.